# Run dotnet test inside docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I want to run the `dotnet test` command inside a docker container but I just cannot figure out where to put the command. The project is a .NET Core 2.1 test project. The reason for this is that I want to run end-to-end integration tests which require all my containers to be running.

DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY Sombra.IntegrationTests/Sombra.IntegrationTests.csproj Sombra.IntegrationTests/
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Sombra.IntegrationTests
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "Sombra.IntegrationTests.csproj"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  sombra.integrationtests:
    image: sombra.integrationtests
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Sombra.IntegrationTests/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 14):

You're using a *runtime* image to invoke the *sdk* command test. Your *final* is from *base* and *base* is from *runtime*.

I've successfully used unit tests as intermediate step while building the container but never integration tests with docker-compose. The key difference is I used a `RUN` command instead of the `entrypoint/cmd` so the tests are already executing while building the container. The main advantage is that there is no *final* image when the tests fail. But then again, this were pure unit tests and no integration tests. Although I can imagine that this will also work.

Here is my full example:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY test.sln ./test.sln
COPY program/program.csproj ./program/program.csproj
COPY program.tests/program.tests.csproj ./program.tests/program.tests.csproj
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet test program.tests -c Release
RUN dotnet publish program -c Release -o /app/out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "program.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a good blog about this. [A guide to setting up a .NET Core project using Docker, with integrated unit and component tests](https://joehonour.medium.com/a-guide-to-setting-up-a-net-core-project-using-docker-with-integrated-unit-and-component-tests-a326ca5a0284)
In this blog look for component tests which is equivalent to what you are trying to do.
Below dockerfile is working for me. This can be build as docker image and then can be used for running integration tests.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln .
COPY ["Somthing.Business/Somthing.Business.csproj", "Somthing.Business/"]
COPY ["tests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests.csproj", "tests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests/"]
COPY "Directory.*.props" . # this is centralized package manager for a project

RUN dotnet restore "tests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "tests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests.csproj"

FROM build AS testrunner
WORKDIR /src/tests/Somthing.Business.IntegrationTests

CMD ["dotnet", "test", "--no-restore"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide us with an error log or something, but my guess is that you're trying to run `dotnet test Sombra.IntegrationTests.csproj` on an image that doesn't have the `dotnet sdk` installed (only the `dotnet runtime`).

The `dotnet runtime` is a version of dotnet core that cannot execute commands (like `test` and `build`). It can only execute dll's (hence the name "runtime").

Comment: I do not have an error log because the container just exits with code 0. The SDK is installed as you can see in the provided DockerFile

Comment: It isn't installed in the `base` container. Could you try to run it from bash? `docker run -it container bash` and then run it yourself from there.