# How to set up github actions to run unit tests for an asp.net application using nunit?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I currently have an Asp.Net (version 4.6) project that my company has just migrated to Github. We currently use Jenkins for our CI/CD pipeline, but are hoping to migrate to github actions. I'd like to create a github action that builds the project and runs the unit tests. The test project is its own DLL and uses NUnit as the test runner.

My current plan is to try to containerize the project and use github action's container actions to try to build it. I know that github actions only builds linux based containers, so I'm not sure if this approach is even possible. I've been able to find resources for containerizing Asp.Net applications, but haven't had much luck with how to integrate containerized applications with github actions. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your unit tests are being run inside the dockerfile then all you need to do is trigger a `docker build` from github actions which will run everything inside the dockerfile, including running tests.

ASP.NET Core runs on linux containers fine and is probably the most popular way to run it containerized.

```
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    ‐ name: build-push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
      with:
        username: ${{ DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        registry: myregistry
        repository: myorg/myrepo
        tags: v1
```

See other resources on how to run nunit tests inside dockerfiles, i believe thats a separate question, e.g. [Run dotnet test inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123486/run-dotnet-test-inside-docker-container/50698655)